# How to import source files in Java to use in another project

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I have been writing a project in Java that I've called `NHL2` and at this point in the development I've decided to try to incorporate `wheels` which can be found [here](http://wps.aw.com/aw_sanders_oopjava_1/36/9390/2403932.cw/index.html).  I've downloaded and unzipped the folder, and tried to import the files in several different ways.  In Eclipse I've tried right-clicking the NHL2 project and importing it.  The files get inserted into certain places in the project but when I type `import wheels.etc.*` for instance, it gives me an error and says it cannot resolve the import.  So I tried deleting the imported files, right-clicking the package containing my files, which is also `NHL2`, and running the import command through there.  Again, same basic problem.

I've also tried just creating a whole separate project titled `wheels` and importing there.  This seems to be fine and the wheels project itself has no errors, but still I cannot import those files in my NHL2 project.  I've tried looking up YouTube videos and other stackoverflow questions because this seems like it's just so basic that it should have been answered by now, but I can't find it.

Comment: include it as an external library to the project

Comment: Are you downloading source files or a JAR? If you are trying to use source files, then you must place the wheel folder inside your src folder for the imports to work like that

Comment: @cricket_007 source files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a new Folder in your Project, e.g. called "lib"
- Copy the wheels.zip into that Folder
- Open the properties of your Project (Alt-Enter on the Project)
- Select "Java Build Path"
- Select the Register Card "Libraries"
- Click "Add JARs"
- Select "Yourproject/lib/wheels.zip"
- Click "OK" then again "OK"

Though it is no jar file (but a zip) it works. I tested it.
This is because the zip contains the class files and the source files as well.

Comment: That worked like a damn dream.  I don't get it, but I very much appreciate your help.